# Gif to base64 encoding without saving file

Tags: python, base64, animated-gif

My gif is just an array of images that save to a `.gif` file. But I need to encode the gif file, is there a way to not save the file as a .gif and encode it?

```py
imageio.mimsave(output_vid + '.gif', [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in gif], fps=fps)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to base64 encode your image in memory you can use below function:

```py
import base64
import io

def _img_to_base64(image, max_size):
    if type(image) is np.ndarray:
        image = Image.fromarray(image)
    elif type(image) is str or type(image) is str_:
        image = Image.open(image)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    image = resize_with_aspect_ratio(image, max_size)
    image.save(output, format='PNG')
    b64 = str(base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()).decode('utf-8'))
    return b64
```

If you'll to share more details on what is your input and desired output I may be able to help out more